# SQL Server JDB connection issue with Java 8 and Tomcat 7.0.53 in Azure Web App

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, datasource

I am calling a web service and after frequently I am getting the below exception, how do I resolve it

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by
>   peer: socket write error\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1745)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1732)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.write(IOBuffer.java:1842)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.flush(IOBuffer.java:4161)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.writePacket(IOBuffer.java:4062)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.endMessage(IOBuffer.java:3107)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6700)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:424)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:372)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1793)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)\r\n\tat
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:315)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)\r\n\tat
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate

I am using Apache Commons `BasicDataSource` for connection pooling, and below is the code for the same

```
ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setUrl(database_url);

        // the settings below are optional -- dbcp can work with defaults
        ds.setMinIdle(10);
        ds.setMaxIdle(50);
        ds.setMaxActive(100);
        ds.setInitialSize(10);
```

Comment: A connection reset by peer generally means that the other side closed the connection. You may want to check SQL Server logs, and check if the version of your JDBC driver is compatible with your SQL Server version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the answer. Can you share any such link which has compatibility chart between JDBC Driver and SQL Server. Also, how to check SQL Server logs on Azure ?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/overview-of-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15